# Adding a WorkDay

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to add a WorkDay. Although there is a lot of information about how to use this in Excel there isn't much about VBA. My code below is mostly stolen from something I found here. Web is bare on this subject.

I am trying to add a day to a date but it cannot include weekends or holidays (familiar with the Excel usage). Each time it adds the WorkDay(Date,1) I seem to come up with a date that ends in 2040.

```
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
d1 = wf.WorkDay(Date, 1)
With rngData
.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "3456", "3125", "3451", "3110", "3370"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
For Each c In wsd.AutoFilter.Range.Range("M2:M" & lngLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    c.Value = c.Value + d1
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

[`WorksheetFunction.WorkDay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.workday)

> Returns a number that represents a **date** that is the indicated number of working days before or after a date (the starting date).

With `d1 = wf.WorkDay(Date, 1)`, you're returning a *date* that you're then adding to other dates in the loop.

Call `WorkDay` on the dates in the loop:

```
c.Value = wf.WorkDay(c.Value, 1)
```

Comment: And we have a winner. Thank You!!! I am not going to brag about my weak vba skills but I was so close so many times.